# Solve This 'Unknown Operator' Problem

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

[Source](https://gpuzzles.com/mind-teasers/quickfire-equation/?external=1&source=stack)

If below equations are true,

```
24 % 6 = 64
35 % 5 = 87
63 % 7 = 99
```

Then based on similar logic what's the value of below equation

```
88 % 8 = ?
```

Comment: going to say **NO** to 'Puzzles of the Day'

Comment: @JonMark, unless the answer involves an infinitesimal or an infinity, it's somewhat misleading to use the word "surreal"

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, please do not make unnecessary edits. Personal preference is not a reason to edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next would be -

> **1611**
>
>  First digit/digits is/are sum of two digits of first number and the next digit/digits is/are division of first and the second.
>
>  8+8 = 16
>  88/8 = 11
>
>  Hence, **1611**
>
>  Others - 
>
>  24 % 6 = 64 $\rightarrow$ 2+4,24/6 $\rightarrow$ **64**
>  35 % 5 = 87 $\rightarrow$ 3+5,35/5 $\rightarrow$ **87**
>  63 % 7 = 99 $\rightarrow$ 6+3,63/7 $\rightarrow$ **99**

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, it could be

> **171** 
>  If you instead look at operator as functioning thusly:  (sum of the digits of the first number)*10 + (first number divided by the second number) 
>  
>  For example: 
>  24 % 6 = (2 + 4)*10 + (24/6) = 64 
>  35 % 5 = (3 + 5)*10 + (35/5) = 87 
>  88 % 8 = (8 + 8)*10 + (88/8) = 171

Without an extra example, I'm afraid this puzzle might be a little ambiguous.